# Android app crashes because of Shared preferrence

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, switching

in the first activity of my app, at start i am checking whether the SharedPreferrence contains some value or not. If it is to be null, it open the first activity, if not i want to open the second activity of my app.

Following is part of my code.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences( "idValue", MODE_WORLD_READABLE );
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.login);
  if(prefs.getString("idValue", "")==null)
    {
        userinfo();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Add.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
}
```

When i checked in logcat it shows error at the following line

But my app gets crashed when the first activity gets opened

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences( "idValue", MODE_WORLD_READABLE );
```

Following is the my logcat details....

```
AndroidRuntime(5747): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
AndroidRuntime(5747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gs.cc.sp/com.gs.cc.sp.UserInfo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime(5747): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime(5747):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
AndroidRuntime(5747):     at com.gs.cc.sp.UserInfo.<init>(UserInfo.java:62)
AndroidRuntime(5747):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(5747):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
AndroidRuntime(5747):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
AndroidRuntime(5747):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
```

Please friends tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: BTW: if(prefs.getString("idValue", "")==null) will never be true, because if there isn't an "idValue", the default value ("") is set, which is not null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accessing the current instance `this` of your class before initiating ,Thats why you are getting nullpointer exception.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.login);
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences( "idValue", MODE_WORLD_READABLE );
  if(prefs.getString("idValue", "")==null)
    {
        userinfo();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Add.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but I'm going to assume that you initialise some user info in your call to `userinfo()`.

What you need to know about `prefs.getString` is that the it will never return `null`. The second argument you provide defines the value it will return if the preference does not exist - so in your example you should probably use:

```
if ( prefs.getString ( "idValue", "" ).equals ( "" ) )
{
    userinfo();
}
```